# Static and Dynamic/Shared Linking with MinGW

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I want to start with a simple linking usage to explain my problem. Lets assume that there is a library `z` which could be compiled to shared library libz.dll(D:/libs/z/shared/libz.dll) or to static library libz.a (D:/libs/z/static/libz.a).

Let I want to link against it, then I do this:

```
gcc -o main.exe main.o -LD:/libs/z/static -lz
```

According to [this documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html), gcc would search for libz.a, which is

> archive files whose members are object files

I also can do the following:

```
gcc -o main.exe main.o -LD:/libs/z/shared -lz
```

It is not mentioned in the documentation above that `-l` flag will search for `lib<name>.so`.

What will happen if I libz.a and libz.dll will be in the same directory? How the library will be linked with a program? Why I need the flags `-Wl,-Bstatic` and `-Wl,-Bdynamic` if `-l` searches both for shared and static libraries?

Why some developers provide .a files with .dll files for the same modules, if I compile a shared library distribution?

For example, Qt provides .dll files in bin directory with .a files in lib directory. Is it the same library, but built like shared and static, respectively? Or .a files are some kind of dummy libraries which provide linking with shared libraries, where there are real library implementations?

Another example is OpenGL library on Windows. Why every compiler must provide the static OpenGL lib like libopengl32.a in MingW?

What are files with .dll.a and .la extensions used for?

P.S. There are a lot of questions here, but I think each one depends on the previous one and there is no need to split them into several questions.

Comment: Let's take the cygwin example: it is my understanding, that programs compiled with cygwin need a certain dll to run. The dll is bound to a certain license (one of the free ones) and has to be present on the host system for the program. If you as a developer forget to ship it along with the program, the program won't run. Another example is version conflicting DLLs (ie opengl). every system has different capabilities and therefore different implementations of certain DLLs. So sometimes the developers like to use the correct library version => static linked.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Please, have a look at [ld and WIN32 (cygwin/mingw)](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/WIN32.html). Especially, the **direct linking to a dll** section for more information on the behavior of `-l` flag on Windows ports of LD. Extract:

> For instance, when ld is called with the argument -lxxx it will attempt to find, in the first directory of its search path,

```
libxxx.dll.a
xxx.dll.a
libxxx.a
cygxxx.dll (*)
libxxx.dll
xxx.dll
```

> before moving on to the next directory in the search path.
>
> (*) Actually, this is not `cygxxx.dll` but in fact is `<prefix>xxx.dll`, where `<prefix>` is set by the ld option `-dll-search-prefix=<prefix>`. In the case of cygwin, the standard gcc spec file includes `-dll-search-prefix=cyg`, so in effect we actually search for `cygxxx.dll`.

**NOTE:** If you have ever built Boost with MinGW, you probably recall that the naming of Boost libraries exactly obeys the pattern described in the link above.

In the past there were issues in MinGW with direct linking to `*.dll`, so it was advised to create a static library `lib*.a` with exported symbols from `*.dll` and link against it instead. The link to this MinGW wiki page is now dead, so I assume that it should be fine to link directly against `*.dll` now. Furthermore, I did it myself several times with the latest MinGW-w64 distribution, and had no issues, yet.

You need link flags `-Wl,-Bstatic` and `-Wl,-Bdynamic` because sometimes you want to force static linking, for example, when the dynamic library with the same name is also present in a search path:

```
gcc object1.o object2.o -lMyLib2 -Wl,-Bstatic -lMyLib1 -Wl,-Bdynamic -o output
```

The above snippet guarantees that the default linking priority of `-l` flag is overridden for `MyLib1`, i.e. even if `MyLib1.dll` is present in the search path, LD will choose `libMyLib1.a` to link against. Notice that for `MyLib2` LD will again prefer the dynamic version.

**NOTE:** If `MyLib2` depends on `MyLib1`, then `MyLib1` is dynamically linked too, regardless of `-Wl,-Bstatic` (i.e. it is ignored in this case). To prevent this you would have to link `MyLib2` statically too.

Comment: You fixed the link, thanks for that, but in the text you still mention this defect: *'The link to this MinGW wiki page is now dead, so I assume […]'* which is a bit confusing. If you find the time, would you please rework it in that respect? Thanks in advance.