# Golang: call Windows DLL functions

Tags: c++, windows, dll, go

I am writing a Go app that calls into a Windows DLL.  The DLL was written with MSVC and has extern "C" exports using __declspec(dllexport).

The top of my Go app is as follows:

```
//#cgo CFLAGS: -IC:/Repos/Module/include
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -L. C:/Repos/Module/go/bin/MyModule.dll
//#include <MyModule.h>
import "C"
```

I'm calling functions from the module like so:

```
nRet := C.moduleImpl_len()
```

The problem is that when I try to run this app, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\MINDO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build836751819\mod\modimpl\_obj\modimpl.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_e2aaf076ab69_Cfunc_moduleImpl_len':
C:/Repos/Module/go/src/mod/modimpl/modimpl.go:90: undefined reference to `moduleImpl_len'
```

I looked at the DLL exported symbols with DUMPBIN and it showed exactly "moduleImpl_len" as the exported symbol.  This is also the symbol as defined in MyModule.h.

Any suggestions on how I can get the symbols to link without having to go the syscall route?

Comment: That was a typo on my part when creating the question.  My code was correct (a single colon).  Now corrected in the question text.

Comment: This was the correct answer.  Why don't you put it in an answer and I'll give you credit.  Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to link against the dll you need/want "-lMyModule" in the LDFLAGS? https://stackoverflow.com/a/15853231/32453

Answer (score 0):

The above will link the DLL in at compile-time which can be desirable in some situations.

In order to link at runtime, one would need to use a syscall package. I was needing to do this on Windows once and [this was the first easy and quick example I found](https://golang.hotexamples.com/examples/syscall/-/NewLazyDLL/golang-newlazydll-function-examples.html#0x54edd45a73453442a7c5b14b9de2ff1a4a4294081ee0606f78c8d3afc2978f66-7,,22,) to help me try doing it the first time