# Is there a way to intercept windows notifications in golang

Tags: go

I found this api exposed in for C# developers and I'm aware there is a way to send toast notifications in Go, my question is:

Is there a way to read notifications that are send to the user's computer?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener

Comment: If all else fails, you could always write the relevant code in C# and compile it into a DLL that you load into your Go program.

Comment: @CherryDT know of anyplace I can read more about this?

Answer (score 0):

I just [looked for *any* Go program](https://github.com/search?l=&q=%22UserNotificationListener%22%20language%3AGo&type=commits) declaring / loading any DLL-like based on `UserNotificationListener`.

There is none to find, which means probably no direct support from Go.
Calling a [C# function from Go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44448542/6309) would therefore be a possible workaround. [`matiasinsaurralde/go-dotnet`](https://github.com/matiasinsaurralde/go-dotnet) might work too, but has not been updated those past few years.

Comment: @madzohan indeed, I will find a better link, and edit the answer

Comment: @madzohan Answer edited.