# codeblocks ld.exe cannot find -lbgi error message

Tags: c++, graphics, compiler-errors, codeblocks, bgi

I am working on BGI library (graphics.h) c++ using **code blocks**. After setting up the library files in folders and linking in compiler settings (screenshot) I am getting the message **ld.exe cannot find -lbgi**

#### Compiler setting screen1

[image: Compiler setting screen1]

#### Compiler setting screen2

[image: Compiler setting screen2]

#### Bulid log

[image: Bulid log]

Comment: You need to tell it to link statically.
-Bstatic -lbgi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852677/static-and-dynamic-shared-linking-with-mingw

Comment: did not work. same thing.

Comment: @user9640019 I also encountered this problem. Were you able to solve this? How did you solve the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Code:Blocks 20.03 IDE
Settinngs>compiler..>Linker settings>Reset defaults>yes>yes>OK

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).