# How can I create a standalone Windows C++ executable using CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, exe

I have a program that depends on

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

Its `CMakeLists` is the following

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(CirclesDetectionProject VERSION 0.1)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release CACHE STRING "Build type" FORCE)

# OpenCV
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS "C:/opencv/build/x64/mingw64/")
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
    main.cpp
)

add_executable(CirclesDetection ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(CirclesDetection ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I'm using VScode on windows 10 and the code compiling and running correctly using `mingw32-make`.

My question is how can I generate an executable that can run on other windows machines that don't necessarily have the dependencies installed?

Comment: One way is to use static linking, so all dependencies are part of the executable. [What do 'statically linked' and 'dynamically linked' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/311882/17398063)

Comment: You'll want to read through this in detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852677/static-and-dynamic-shared-linking-with-mingw but you hopefully have static versions of the libraries you're linking against.  Otherwise you've got an uphill battle to produce them yourself.

Comment: please go through the first page of https://www.google.com/search?q=cmake+create+standalone+application+site:stackoverflow.com and see if any of the existing Q&A answer your question. There seem to already be tons of questions about this.

Comment: @BoP Fully statically linking an executable is not always (easily) possible.

Comment: You need to read the cmake documentation about the `install` command. In most cases it can handle your needs.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Thanks I'll check that for my information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `CFE explorer` which tells you all ddls that the exe need, which is very useful. in my case, it showed me that I have those dependencies:

```
libwinpthread-1.dll
libopencv_core480.dll
libopencv_imgcodecs480.dll
liboopencv_imgproc480.dll
kernel32.dll
msvcrt.dll
```

For `libwinpthread-1.dll` I had to add this to my `CMakeLists` to ensure static linking:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")
```

Then for `OpenCV`, I did recompile it from source in static mode and recompile my code using the static version of OpenCV. Make sure it is using the static one:

```
set(OpenCV_DIR "C:/opencv-4.7.0-static/build/x64/mingw64/")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
```

Finally, for `kernel32.dll` and `msvcrt.dll`, they are standard windows system libraries and they are present on every Windows machine, so you don't have to worry about them.